Alpine - Switch to node v20
Serverless requires node > 18
So, in the deploy script I added these statements.
$ apk add nodejs --no-cache --repository="http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.20/main/" --allow-untrusted

fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.20/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz

fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz

fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz

OK: 821 MiB in 153 packages

$ apk add npm --no-cache --repository="http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.20/main/" --allow-untrusted

fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.20/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz

fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz

fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz

OK: 821 MiB in 153 packages

$ node --version
v14.21.3

What command do I need, to switch the node version to the new one in v3.20?

I tried to add in this command just before the node --version line, thinking it would use v3.20 to update, nope.
$ apk add --update nodejs npm
$ node --version v14.21.3


Modified dind to v20.10.16-dind in gitlab and code quality ymls
Serverless - we always install the latest (now v4) - this is a Best Practice.  However, starting with v4 they require a paid license key.  Also v4 requires a nodJS version > 18, thus the dind update.  Modified the serverless install in the deploy yml to specify 3.39.  V3 is only supported through 2024.
We will be switching to terraform before the end of the year.

